# Care of CPL filter: is this a fungus?

Tags: filters, fungus

Found an old PLC filter in my bag. Unused for years (git it for the kit lens of my first DSLR). There is strange spot on it, apparently under the front glass:

Situational awareness: this is the big spot slightly above and left of center:

[image]

Close up:

[image]

Is it easily fixable (not a very expensive filter anyway, so ready to throw it away...)?

Also, are there good sleeves to carry filters, that protect them from shocks, don't tke an enormous space, and can be fitted with some silicagel (if this is a way to prevent fungus)?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning it? What did you try and did it look any different after than before? Can you feel the spot with your finger?

Comment: Do you mean CPL (circular polarizing filter)? PLC filters are electrical power line filters to eliminate noise and allow power line communication.

Comment: @MichaelC Yes, meant CPL, and yes, although I couldn't feel it with my fingers, it turned out to be cleanable. I still wonder how this thing came there, maybe it's fungus anyway? Also the question about what a good filter box/sleeve looks like still holds.

Comment: I keep most of my filters stacked in a cottage cheese tub with index card separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like dirt/dried mud to me. It does not have the characteristic "spiderweb" look of typical lens fungus.

[image]

I've always carried my CPL in the square plastic case that it came in.